# How to reset index for pandas.core.series

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe contains a string column 'code_desc' which contains  with codes in it.

I have a pandas.core.series generated by the code below:

```
d = {'R438': 'The person is a Ninja',
     'R727': 'The person is a Pirate',
.....}


pat = r'\b(%s)\b' % '|'.join(d)
codes = df['codes_desc'].str.extractall(pat)[0]
df['reference'] = codes.map(d).groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)
```

Here is the output of 'codes'

```
   matches
0  0        R438
   1        R727
   2        R662
1  0        R438
   1        R727
   2        R662
2  0        R438
   1        R727
   2        R662
3  0        R438
   1        R727
   2        R662
4  0        R438
   1        R727
   2        R662
5  0        R438
   1        R727
   2        R662
0  0        R227
   1        R438
   2        R727
5  0        R223
4  0        R223
```

I have tried using `.reset_index(level=1, inplace=True, drop=True)` but this seems not to be working as I want to reset the index for it.

Expected output :

```
   matches
0  0        R438
   1        R727
   2        R662
1  0        R438
   1        R727
   2        R662
2  0        R438
   1        R727
   2        R662
3  0        R438
   1        R727
   2        R662
4  0        R438
   1        R727
   2        R662
5  0        R438
   1        R727
   2        R662
6  0        R227
   1        R438
   2        R727
7  0        R223
8  0        R223
```

May you please let me know; how to achieve this.

Comment: Could you please attach code for the Series creation?

Comment: Is is series a result of a `pd.concat`?

Comment: Hi @QuangHoang I have added explanation to the code